# Telerik MVC Editor Insert Image - Only display the loading animation and image name

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-mvc, telerik-editor

We're currently using Telerik's MVC editor, specifically for browsing images to select.  The editor shows, allows a popup screen and finds all the images in the content folder, however, the loading animation spinner is next to each image and never resolves the thumbnail.  Next to each spinner has the name of each image so I know it's at least looking in the correct spot, however it will just spin away never actually showing the thumbnails.

Here's the view code:

```
@{Html.Telerik().EditorFor(m => m.ProductImageSize.Filename)
                        .Tools(tools => tools.Clear().InsertImage())
                              .FileBrowser(browser => browser.Browse("Browse", "ProductImageBrowser")
                              .Thumbnail("Thumbnail", "ProductImageBrowser")
                              .Upload("Upload", "ProductImageBrowser")
                              .DeleteFile("DeleteFile", "ProductImageBrowser"))
                        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:450px; height:400px;" })
                        .Render();
        }
```

Selecting the images works too! it's just difficult to tell which image you're selecting since the user only has the name of the image to go off of.

any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to "fix" the issue by upgrading my version of Telerik.  Not really a solution but from their support pages, it appears to be a but in their code.

Comment: Spend more money seems to be a common answer to a lot of Telerik problems.